# JMS filtering using XPATH

Tags: xpath, jms, soa

i have a requirement in which i need to filter JMS messages according to XPATH.

I tried to use a jca property as shown below. But it did not pick  any JMS messages.

> property name="MessageSelector" value="JMS_BEA_SELECT('xpath','/ns1:books/ns1:book[2]/ns1:price/text()') = '20'"/>

i tried to use multiple variants in the value part but anything doesn't work.

Is any syntax available for this or any other way for doing this task.

NOTE: i do not want to use headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you cannot use XPATH in selectors when using JMS. However, ActiveMQ supports Xpath selectors: http://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html

Obviously, your messages must then be `TextMessage`s containing XML bodies, as above documentation suggests.